# Bootstrap Dialog (nakupanda) getting form values [JSFiddle]

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've trouble getting values out of my form.

I'm using bootstrap dialog from nakupanda (http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/)

The dialog (it is in a fullcalendar select function)

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/

```
var form = $('#createEventForm').html();
    BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: form,
         buttons: [{
                label: 'Enkel rooster event',
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    console.log('enkel - create')
                    dialogItself.close();                           
                }
            },{
                label: 'Herhalend rooster event (elke dag)',
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    console.log('meer - create')
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            },{
                label: 'Close',
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    console.log(dialogItself);
                     alert('The content of the dialog is: ' + dialogItself.getModal().html());
            }
        }]
    });
```

The html form

```
<form id="createEventForm">
    <label>Klantnaam</label>
    <input type="text" id="titleDrop" />
    <br/>
    <label>Beschrijving</label>
    <input type="text" id="descriptionDrop" />
</form>
```

I don't know how to retrieve the data from the forms input when someone clicks on a button. `I've tried $(titleDrop).val()`and`getElementById(titleDrop)`

Sometimes the form can contain php.

I am not getting javascript errors. I just don't get anything back when clicking on the butotns and using  `$('titleDrop').val()`

**EDIT** FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/jochem4207/7DcHW/3

This code works:

```
var form = '<label>Klantnaam</label><input type="text" id="titleDrop"><br><label>Beschrijving</label><input type="text" id="descriptionDrop">';
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                message: form,

                buttons: [{
                    id: 'submit1',
                    label: 'See what you got',
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function(dialogRef){
                        var titleDropVal = $('#titleDrop').val();
                        console.log(titleDropVal);
                    }
                }]
            });
```

Still curious if it could work when I dont add the html in the JS section.

**Edit: Question 2**

I have a select list that gets filled from php

```
                   var select = $('<select id="selectVisibleUser"></select>');

            <?php 
            $userList = array();

            foreach($this->users as $user){
                $jsUser = array(
                    'key'  => $user->webuserId,
                    'value'=> $user->firstName.$user->preposition.$user->lastName
                );
                array_push($userList, $jsUser);
            }
            $list = Zend_Json::encode($userList);
            ?>


            $.each(<?php echo $list?>, function(key, value) {
                select.append($("<option/>", {
                    value: key,
                    text: value
                }));
            });


            BootstrapDialog.show({
                message: function (dialogItself){
                    var form = $('<form></form>');
                    dialogItself.setData('select-visible', select);
                    form.append('<label>Select</label>').append(select);
                    return form;

                },
                buttons: [{
                    id: 'submit1',
                    label: 'See what you got',
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function(dialogItself){
                        alert(dialogItself.getData('select-visible').val());
                    }
                }]
            });
```

This shows me a empty select list and returns offcourse a null when I click the button.
Should I use your first fiddle in this case?

Tried the first fiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/b8AJJ/1/ ) works perfectly in this case (except i've some trouble to get the id instead of the value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/b8AJJ/

If possible I would suggest this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/7DcHW/4/

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
    message: function (dialogItself) {
        var $form = $('<form></form>');
        var $titleDrop = $('<input type="text" />');
        dialogItself.setData('field-title-drop', $titleDrop);   // Put it in dialog data's container then you can get it easier by using dialog.getData() later.
        $form.append('<label>Title Drop</label>').append($titleDrop);

        return $form;
    },
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Get title drop value.',
        action: function (dialogItself) {
            alert(dialogItself.getData('field-title-drop').val());
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: thats genius, thanks! I used the second suggestion. The first one doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Super, second choice for me to, I was just wondering how to do that.

Comment: The problem with the second solution is that the input box is in a form.  When this has focus and there is something in the box then if you press enter the main form reloads.    var $form = $('<form></form>'); should be changed to  var $form = $('<div> </div> '); and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

You're using element selector wrong.

Try `$('#titleDrop').val()` instead of `$(titleDrop).val()`.

---

Bind submit event to your form. This way you can get the values of form inputs when the form is submitted. Look at the following example:

http://jsbin.com/xiruv/1/

Comment: oops, that was a typo. It returns nothing. I think because of the html value stays empty

Comment: This would perfectly work but i'm not (yet) using buttons in my form. I was trying to use the buttons the modal generates. Do you have a idea for that?

Comment: I don't know what kind of button the script generates, but if the button ables you to send the form, it should work just fine. If you can provide a working example (jsfiddle, jsbin etc.), I look at it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jochem4207/7DcHW/1/ took a while to fix the js/css.

I need to get the values of the "klantnaam" and "beschrijving"

Comment: I think the problem is the $('#titleDrop').val() returns empty because it doesn't get it from the form in the modal box but from the form on the html page